# Export Mender devices from old Mender account to new

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, mender

I use Mender.io, I have my old mender account, and now i create new mender account. How i can migrate all devices to new account ?
I use hosted Mender (no mender server).
My IoT devices is azure, and i use Azure DevOps to release.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will in general need to update the configuration (mender.conf) on your devices to point to the new server. If both are with hosted.mender.io you just a new Tenant Token. This can be done with an OTA update in Mender.

Please see here for more information (even if you're not moving from self-hosted the general steps are the same): https://hub.mender.io/t/migration-to-hosted-mender-from-self-hosted-one/1076